# How to get the initial height of a React Native component

Tags: react-native

In our code we're currently using onLayout to store the heights of various components.

However, the layout occasionally changes

1) Is this the best way to get the heights of components in React Native?

2) What's the best way to prevent repeat calls?

We can do just an if check in the functions on whether the value exists, but this still means the layout function's being unnecessarily called.

Example code:

```
storeHeaderHeight(event) {
    this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        maxHeight: event.nativeEvent.layout.height
    });
}

storeContentHeight(event) {
    this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        minHeight: event.nativeEvent.layout.height
    });
}
```

....

```
<View style={styles.header} onLayout={e => this.storeHeaderHeight(e)}>
  <Text style={styles.caret}>{isExpanded ? 'v' : '^'}</Text>
  <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
</View>
```

....

```
<View style={styles.content} onLayout={e => this.storeContentHeight(e)}>
  {this.props.children}
</View>
```

Comment: You also can try `measure` method on view. More info [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation.html)

Comment: @RajendranNadar `Dimensions` give view port dimension, this is cannot give information about view dimension. Please try your solution before tell others